# SSIS throwing an error when I use Script Task with C# script

Tags: c#, ssis

I don't know much about C# scripting so excuse my noob question

I have a package in SSIS that I use this script component using C#, the package runs fine when I disable the script component and it gives me an error when I enable it.
the script uses two variables to store:
1-file path
2-file name
and I have the same variables in SSIS

I added this to the namespaces

```
using System.IO;
```

then the code as follows:

```
public void Main()
{
    // TODO: Add your code here

    string strfileName;
    string strfilePath;

    strfilePath = Dts.Variables["User::VAR_FilePath"].Value.ToString(); 

    strfileName = Path.GetFileName(strfilePath); // Get the file name

    Dts.Variables["User::VAR_FileName"].Value=strfileName;

    MessageBox.Show(strfileName);

    Dts.TaskResult = (int)ScriptResults.Success;
}
```

Whenever I run it I get the message box that shows the file type, which is excel and then the debugging stops and

Comment: can you please provide the exception details

Comment: `and then the debugging stops and` so does your question.

Comment: Your code declares 2 variables. Populates the first from an SSIS variable. Uses the System.IO.Path class to strip out the filename from the path. You update an SSIS variable with that value and then pop a message box show the same filename. After that, code execution is complete. Assigning Success to the Dts.TaskResult is not cause a failure. If you had managed to erase the enums below the main method, it wouldn't have compiled so it feels like there's code missing from your example

Comment: Have you actually passed in those variables? Does it work when you run this in direclty VS?  Also, add a try-catch block and set a break point.